# Nginx config: rewrite 404s to two possible locations: /blog/index.php or /index.php

Tags: nginx

I need to route all 404s to `/index.php` unless `/blog/` is present in the beginning of the URL, then I need to route it to `/blog/index.php`.

In other words, I have four URLS:

```
example.com/
example.com/my-page/
example.com/blog/
example.com/blog/my-post/
```

And I need to route these to either my main site's `index.php` file or my blog's `index.php` file.
I'm aware I can achieve this with PHP, using a require, but this is a better-suited task for Nginx.
I managed to achieve the desired behavior using the following approach below:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/;
}

if (!-e $request_filename)
{
    # Wordpress Blog
    rewrite ^/blog($|/.*) /blog/index.php break;
    # Main Site
    rewrite ^ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args break;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index /index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

However I want to achieve this without the aid of the `rewrite` directive.
I've tried the following with no luck:

```
location /blog/  {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
}

location /  {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?_url=$uri&$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index /index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

The above serves 3 out of the 4 correctly but not `/blog/my-post/` which yields an Nginx 404 page.

I tried things like `location ~ /blog/` and `location ^~ /blog/`. The former yields no difference, while the latter yields me an ugly gateway error. I would prefer to avoid an `^~` solution so I'm not nesting config in a redundant manner. In such a case, I'd sooner stick to my `rewrite` solution.

What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `$uri/` term and just using `try_files $uri /blog/index.php;`?

Comment: @RichardSmith tried that, Nginx 404 page. In fact, I even tried omitting the entire `location /blog/` section, to have both the main site and blog go through the same index.php file. Nginx 404. And just to be sure I'm not running into some sort of caching issue, I was able to edit back to the rewrites, and verify they still work, and back again to try_files, and the same 404.